# what is the meaning of "moral character" in this context?

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning

what is the meaning of "moral character" in this context?

> During these years of public mediumship, when the girls were all the
>   rage among those who had no conception of the religious significance
>   of this new revelation, and who concerned themselves with it purely in
>   the hope of worldly advantage, the sisters exposed themselves to the
>   enervating influences of promiscuous séances in a way which no earnest
>   Spiritualist could justify. The dangers of such practices were not
>   then so clearly realized as now, nor had it occurred to people that it
>   is unlikely that high spirits would descend to earth in order to
>   advise as to the state of railway stocks or the issue of love affairs.
>   The ignorance was universal, and there was no wise mentor at the elbow
>   of these poor pioneers to point the higher and the safer path. Worst
>   of all, their jaded energies were renewed by the offer of wine at a
>   time when one at least of them was hardly more than a child. It is
>   said that there was some family predisposition towards alcoholism, but
>   even without such a taint their whole procedure and mode of life were
>   rash to the last degree. Against their **moral character** there has never
>   been a breath of suspicion, but they had taken a road which leads to
>   degeneration of mind and character, though it was many years before
>   the more serious effects were manifest.

from http://gutenberg.net.au/ebooks03/0301051h.html

Answer (score 1):

Moral character is acknowledgement or disregard of proper and/or acceptable behavior.

The girls moral character "or disregard for proper behavior" is made evident with their use of alcohol and questionable practices.

The placement of the preposition **against** is the key. An updated version might read
"Despite their moral character, no suspicion had been spoken of..."

Answer (score 0):

According to [this article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moral_character) (emphasis mine):

> **Moral character** or **character** is an evaluation of an individual's stable moral qualities. The concept of character can imply a variety of attributes including the existence or lack of virtues such as empathy, courage, fortitude, honesty, and loyalty, or of good behaviors or habits. Moral character primarily refers to the assemblage of qualities that distinguish one individual from another—although on a cultural level, the set of moral behaviors to which a social group adheres can be said to unite and define it culturally as distinct from others.

In other words, it's all the traits a person has that makes them "good" or "bad", and defines their identity from a moral standpoint.

Comment: does "Against their moral character there has never been a breath of suspicion" means that they were morally good?

Comment: Speaking "against somebody's moral character" means to essentially accuse them of wrongdoing. Not necessarily illegal, criminal acts, but immoral ones, things that make them look like a bad person, if not exactly a criminal. What "breath of suspicion" means here is basically "the least amount of suspicion", a "breath" being the smallest possible utterance from a person's mouth. It's a kind of poetic understatement. So all together it means "nobody spoke even a little badly about them." Or you could also take it to mean "there were no bad rumors about their behavior".